# Make Laravel 5 and Angular 5 work on the same domain/port

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I want to **avoid cors** so I would like to make Laravel serve my Angular frontend. My backend already works like an API but for security and simplicity, I would like to merge the two parts.

Is there a good way to implement it as you can do with Vue.js? Did someone already did that?

I already made some tests by building the dist in the views and serving it with a laravel route

**angular.json** :

```
...
    "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../resources/views/front",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
...
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    View::addExtension('html', 'php');
    if (View::exists('front.index')) {
        return view('front.index');
    }
    return view('welcome');
});
```

The problem is that I can't test my app in hmr mode and Laravel doesn't seem to accept javascript inside of `views/` folder...

I tried to put all javascript in `ressources/assets/js` but I don't know if I can specify it in *angular.json* to do it automatically.

Comment: I think your dist needs to be placed in your public folder of your Laravel project, not the views folder. The views are templates.

Comment: Oh okay, I should try this. So then how do I call the index that will be in the public folder?

Comment: Any index.html in the public folder should be rendered by your Laravel application when you load it. I don't think you need to explicitly call it. Have a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@juancarlosjc/angular-inside-laravel-b155736ea84b)

Comment: Because this could interfer with my routes

Comment: For now I found a temporary workaround. I will come back here lather to find a solution and write it here.

Comment: Fun fact, the cors seems to be environment problems. If a mysql client is connected to the database, CORS appears. And sometimes it pops out from nowhere until I reeboot my environnement completely.